# In Python how to pipe a string into an executables stdin?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pipe

On Windows I have a program (prog.exe) that reads from stdin. In python I want to pipe a string as the input to its stdin. How to do that?

Something like:

```
subprocess.check_output("echo {0} | myprog.exe".format(mystring))
```

or (to make the args a list)

```
subprocess.check_output("echo {0} | myprog.exe".format(mystring).split())
```

doesn't seem to work. It gave me:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried to use the "stdin" keyword arg with StringIO (which is a file-like object)

```
subprocess.check_output(["myprog.exe"], stdin=StringIO(mystring))
```

Still no luck - check_output doesn't work with StringIO.

Comment: Note that the answer by `wim` is definitely the way to go here, however, your attempt would probably work if you used `shell=True` in your `check_output` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use Popen `communicate` method ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)).

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["myprog.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('my input')
```